# React: state-based styling

Tags: css, reactjs

I have the following React component:

```
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      content: 'bad'
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="content-div">
        {this.state.content}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I want to render the `<div>` based on the text of `this.state.content`, i.e. if the text is `'bad'`, the background color is red, and if the text is not `'bad'`, then the color is green.

What is the best way of doing this via CSS (or maybe there's other preferable way)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there are many ways to do this, here's the regular way

```
<div className="content-div" style={this.state.content === 'bad' ? {backgroundColor: 'red'} : {backgroundColor: 'green'} }>
        {this.state.content}
      </div>
```

**Update:**

As I prefer you to use the same syntax for the class

```
<div className={this.state.content === 'bad' ? 'myBadClass' : 'MyGreenClass'} >
        {this.state.content}
      </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And what's the syntax when there are several style elements that need to be changed?

Comment: You can simply use the same syntax for class name, I updated my answer